# I have Netherlands residence permit but Turkish passport. Can I visit Bulgaria for 3 days?

Tags: visas

As I mentioned I have normal Turkish passport and Netherlands residence permit
Can I travel Bulgaria without visa for 3 days?

Answer (score 4):

TIMATIC states :

> > Notice Bulgaria - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required. Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a "D" visa issued by Cyprus, Romania or a Schengen
> Member State for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> > The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Netherlands for a maximum
> stay of 90 days.
>
> > The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

You can visit Bulgaria visa-free for 90 days/180 days based on your Residence Permit from the Netherlands